# Simulate or have VcXsrv system menu on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a debian package which wants to install
a system menu icon. Installation failed, and
now deinstallion also fails with:

```
xdg-desktop-menu: No writable system menu directory found.
```

The situation was already worse. The above gives
me only exit code 3. Before the exit code was 127,
since xdg-utils were not yet installed.

Is there a way to simulate a system menu and make
the error go away. Or even better to have a system menu
in WSL that works together with Windows VcXsrv?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this could be a solution for the simulation:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/desktop-directories/
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/405800